# Need Sweet Alert to prevent keypress like regular alert

Tags: alert, confirm, sweetalert

I want a confirmation alert to pop up, but I want it to look nice so I'm using sweet alert. The problem is users can still press buttons while the sweet alert is up which is bad for my site. On a normal alert all the functions are frozen until the alert is closed. Can I get that functionality with sweet alert?

Answer (score 0):

you can edit sweet alert to block outside clic and esc keys to force the user to cancel or accept the action blocking another part of your page

allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false,
  allowEnterKey: false,

you need to download the library and import it locally, edit those lines in the code